# Identify the version of libstdc++

Tags: c++, libstdc++

I've come across [Bug 58800](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58800) in `libstdc++`, which causes some of my code to segfault. I have a workaround, but I don't want to use it when a fixed version of `libstdc++` is available. What is the right way to check for the version of `libstdc++` (via `ifdef`)? And, ideally, which versions are affected by this bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libstdc++ comes with GCC, so the correct way is to check the GCC version, by testing its `__GNUC__`, `__GNUC_MINOR__` and `__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__` [predefined macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html).

If you're using libstdc++ with Clang you could test whether `__GLIBCXX__ > 20131020UL` which is the date the bug was fixed. A release after that date should contain the fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `__GLIBCXX__` macro to check the version information for `libstdc++`.  (There's a list of values in section 7 of the [ABI Policy Appendix](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html).)

The bug finishes with a list of versions which have been fixed, but figuring out when the bug was introduced might be trickier. If you were using `autoconf`, I'd suggest writing a test which crashed if the bug was present.

Comment: I've seen the list in ABI Policy Appendix, but it doesn't go far enough. The problem is fixed in 4.8.3, but the list stops at 4.8.0. A test is a great idea, I need to investigate it better.

Comment: @foxcub: if you have 4.8.3, you could just look at what the macro is set to, no? It's not going to be changed to anything earlier.

Comment: I don't have 4.8.3, which is the problem. But it's Ok, I'll just wait and see.

Comment: @foxcub: if you have 4.8.2, then check to make sure the version date is greater than that.